# Let ξ and η be random variables defined on the same probability space. Prove that the following sets are events

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

Let  ξ and η be random variables defined on the same probability space. Prove that the following sets are events:
A = {ω ∈ Ω : ξ(ω) < η(ω)},
B = {ω ∈ Ω : ξ(ω) = η(ω)},
C = {ω ∈ Ω : ξ(ω) <= η(ω)},

Comment: For the set $A$, one way to proceed is as follows: (1) since $\xi$ and $\eta$ are random variables, can you show that $\xi - \eta$ is also a random variable, (2) then rewrite $A$ in terms of the new random variable $\xi - \eta$, (3) use the 'defining property' of random variables to show that $A$ is an event.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How exactly can I show that − is a random variable?